# Whats the replacement for typealias in Julia?

Tags: julia

```
julia> typealias
ERROR: UndefVarError: typealias not defined
```

it's working in Julia:0.5 but is not working in above versions

```
help?> typealias
search: typealias

  Introduce a new name for an already expressible type. For example, in
  base/boot.jl, UInt is type aliased to either UInt64 or UInt32 as appropriate
  for the size of pointers on the system:

  if is(Int,Int64)
      typealias UInt UInt64
  else
      typealias UInt UInt32
  end

  For parametric types, typealias can be convenient for providing names in
  cases where some parameter choices are fixed. In base for example:

  typealias Vector{T} Array{T,1}
```

So is there any other function or keyword that can be used and works the same way?

Comment: A general hint is that if you're trying to figure out replacements, run an older version of Julia. On Julia-0.6: `julia> typealias MyInt Int

WARNING: deprecated syntax "typealias MyInt Int" at REPL[1]:1.
Use "const MyInt = Int" instead.
Int64`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that with 0.5 it was working fine and in 0.7 it wasn't working

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two ways to define a type alias, which can be seen in the following example:

```
julia> const MyVector1 = Array{T,1} where T
Array{T,1} where T

julia> MyVector2{T} = Array{T,1}
Array{T,1} where T
```

You can see that both of these type aliases are equivalent to the built-in `Vector` type alias:

```
julia> Vector
Array{T,1} where T
```

See [Type Aliases](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Type-Aliases-1) and [UnionAll Types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#UnionAll-Types-1) in the manual for more information.